# Cannot load Ubuntu after loading Windows

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, windows-10

My laptop is a Sony Vaio SVT1412ACXS and came with Win8 before I upgraded it to Win10. Recently, I installed Ubuntu 18.04 **with manual partition** on my laptop. I did a dual boot.

**Fast startup is switched off and Secure Boot is disabled.**

Every time I use Ubuntu, shut down my laptop and open it up again, I see the GRUB screen. But every time I use Windows, shut down my laptop, and open it up to use Ubuntu, the Windows boot loader kicks in and loads Windows on.

I read that one solution (that works for me) is to set boot mode from UEFI to Legacy, restart the computer and set boot mode back to UEFI. Is there a method faster than this? Like HP Laptops have a function key from which they can choose what OS do they load

Comment: There is most certainly a key you can press during early boot that lets you choose a boot entry. A quick google search says F11. Have you tried that?

Comment: @NirmalKhedkar define "use windows", are you selecting it from the grub boot menu or using Bios to boot to it?

Comment: @danzel I've tried it, doesn't work. Sony laptops have a ASSIST button to open BIOS. The key shortcuts are a bit different here.

Comment: @tatsu I select Windows Boot Manager to boot in Windows every time I want to.

Comment: @Nirmal ...and you tried ASSIST+F11 ?

Comment: @danzel that does not work...

Comment: @danzel yeah it doesn't...

Answer (score 1):

Depends on grub installation method. Did you install it UEFI or legacy boot mode?

Seems than you have now mixed UEFI and legacy type bootloaders on your different OS:es.

Comment: Im kinda like a noob in this, but I'll tell you this: I installed Ubuntu when Boot Mode was in its default settings (UEFI).

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI Hope this explains better.

Comment: @NirmalKhedkar yes UEFI is default for ubuntu nowadays but your windows might have been older and still been in Legacy at the time of it's installation?

Comment: @tatsu I dont think so... My laptop released on 2010, so I think Windows was installed on UEFI only .. Besides I never changed that Boot mode setting until recently when I want to switch back up Ubuntu after Windows...

Comment: you touching boot settings wouldn't have changed anything you cannot change from Legacy to Uefi or vise versa once the OS is already installed. ok so it's probably not this.

Comment: This is clearly some bios issue, keeping mind the fact how 8086 bootup sequence is made after processor is reseted. Your laptop have intel smart response technology (https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/smart-response-technology.html), that could made something to accelerate booting. Is it possible to disable this from bios?